# Why can a piece of paper be folded along a straight line but not along a curved line?

Tags: material-science, curvature, elasticity

It seems that if something can be stretched then it can be folded along a curved line. Since paper can't be stretched I can't fold it along a curve. But it's just an observation not an answer to the question. Does anyone know the answer? Is it because of some kind of area conservation?

Comment: I‘m not sure about this thus I don‘t make it an answer. The conservation  you are looking for is possibly the Gaussian curvature. When you bend paper without destroying its internal structure, the Gaussian curvature is always conserved. You can bend paper into a tube but not into a sphere because flat paper and the tube have the same Gaussian curvature but a different one than a sphere.

Comment: "It doesn't stretch" looks like an answer to me. An observation can be an answer. Conservation of area is a property of materials which do not stretch.

Comment: How does a classic fast food French Fry container get folded along a curve? Is it made from special stretchy cardboard?

Comment: I don't understand this question very well. If you are talking only about elastic deformations and you have a strip of paper, then you have the problem of the elastica studied by J. and D. Bernoulli, Euler, Lagrange, et al. In the elastica, the inner part of the fold is compressed while the outer part is stretched but the central part (known is neutral line) remains isometric. If you have a wider piece of paper, then you have the problem of plate deformation. I believe the standard model for these deformations is the Föppl-Von Kármán model.

Comment: If the curvature is not very high you may make a lot of deformations. See for example this problem: "The shape of a Möbius strip" by E. L. STAROSTIN AND G. H. M. VAN DER HEIJDEN in Nature Materials 2007 doi:10.1038/nmat1929. This seems to be a counter example to your claim as stated above, at least as I understood it.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, while you can't fold paper along a curve in 2 dimensions, you can do it in 3 dimensions.

[This article from the journal Physics](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/s139) describes how a flat ring of paper, folded along its circular center, deforms into a saddle as the material buckles to absorb the stresses.

(Longer discussion at [Physicsworld](https://physicsworld.com/a/physicists-unfold-the-mechanics-of-origami/) courtesy of an answer to a related question.)

Answer (score 2):

No, paper can't be stretched because its structure contains no slippage mechanisms which would allow it. To some extent, you can provide slippage by wetting the paper into mush, which unlocks the entanglements between the paper fibers and allows the sheet to deform.

Comment: I'm not asking why paper can't be stretched. But assuming paper can't be stretched, why can't it be folded along a curved line?

Comment: to fold it along a curved line requires the paper to be stretched in some directions and compressed in others.

Answer (score 2):

The short path between 2 points on the paper before folding is a straight line, all points of which belong to the paper.

Now suppose that we managed to completely fold it along a curve between these 2 points. All paths between them on the paper are now curves, with bigger lengths compared to the straight line, (which passes out of the paper).

So, it is not possible to fold it along curves keeping the same distance between all points. And  it requires streching to change distances.

Answer (score 0):

Paper can be more-or-less folded along a curve. You can do it with your fingers.

[image]

It could be argued that this is really just a lot of little short straight lines.

[image]

But it could be argued that any curve is just a lot of little short straight lines.

Comment: That's a plastic deformation along the crease.  In a plastic deformation, which is irreversible, paper can stretch, not by much though, otherwise it would tear. I believe the problem should be restricted to elastic deformations.

Comment: I probably disagree. You can make two straight creases that intersect. You can make a third crease that intersects the first two. You can make two more creases that intersect pairs of the first three. Etc.

You can make lots of creases that approximate a curve. 

And a straight crease involves some stretching too.

But I suspect you're making a philosophical point which is not affected by real paper.

Comment: If you allow for plastic deformations you might as well just crumple a piece of paper and make far more complex 3d curve creases.

Answer (score 0):

The supposition that "something" must be conserved is correct. That something is the flat angle of the material. At every point on a flat sheet of paper (a plane), there is 360° of flat angle about the point. When you fold the paper, it necessarily turns into a 3D shape, but it still has 360° of flat angle at each point along the folded edge. If the fold is straight, then there is 180° on either side of the fold totaling 360 and everything is cool. Furthermore, the material on either side of the fold remains flat as in the sides of a box. However, if the fold follows a curve (which it certainly can), then the flat angle on the convex side of the fold is larger than the angle on the concave side. A consequence of this mismatch is that the paper arches up into two simple curved surfaces on either side of the fold.  Compound curves - arched surfaces where no straight line passes through a particular point as in a dome - cannot be generated from a flat sheet without cutting or stretching.

In a related thought experiment, consider a cube.  At each corner of the cube, 3 sides come together.  Each side forms a 90° angle at the corner. So there are $3 \times 90° = 270°$ of flat angle at the corner.  If you are folding this shape from a single flat sheet of paper, that means you had to remove 90° of flat angle from the sheet to form the corner. (It is also possible to add more flat angle by cutting the sheet and pasting in extra paper.) Since there are 8 corners on the cube, that means $8 \times 90° = 720°$ are removed from the entire cube. It turns out that no matter how many corners a solid object has or how irregular it might be, 720° of flat angle have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Paper represent a flat surface with no elasticity, view from the side (say Z-plane), a flat surface is basically a line.
The next question is what is mean by "folding". I think it mean the two surface "coincide" with no distance between them. From the side view, it mean it is the same meaning of no distance between two points at the point of folding, that is a "single" point (from Z-plane). Take a horizontal folding as an example, in 3D view, it is a straight-line (with same Z-plane co-ordination but different X, Y coordinate). From the point of view of Z-plane, a curve line represent more than one points, that mean the paper need to be torn apart so as to curve, which is impossible.